# problem with abbreviated day in gnuplot

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a graph using gnuplot (v4.4.3)on linux with the input file containing time (X axis)and some other values.
(Sample line - Tue Aug  2 17:00:09 2011  1.8  2.1  1.1  1.1  2.8)
The time is the output from C function - asctime. However I am getting error whenever I try to plot. I am setting the time format as - %a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y. But it always throws an error for illegal day of month,bad abbreviated month etc. I tested it on some other small file and found out that whenever there is abbreviated day in the file it blows up.The documentation says I will have to use %a for abbreviated day and I am doing just that.Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that there is no `%a - abbreviated name of day of the week` in `set timefmt` and cannot be used therefore. It seems to exist however in the `set format` specifier.

The following example should lead you the way:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"
set format x "%H/%a"
plot "-" u 1:5 w lp
    Aug 2 17:00:09 2011 1
    Aug 3 02:00:09 2011 2
    Aug 4 22:00:09 2011 3
    Aug 5 04:00:09 2011 4
    e
```